# Django models: add index on date, desc order

Tags: python, django, indexing

I am trying to make Django models create me an index on a date field on descending (DESC) order and I can't find a way to do it. Basically, I need to do something like the following SQL (in Posgres):

```
CREATE INDEX "idx_name" ON "table" ("date" DESC);
```

The closest I can get is to add `db_index=True` to the model which produces me the following SQL:

```
CREATE INDEX "idx_name" ON "table" ("date");
```

Close, but not quite it. The DESC makes a lot of difference here since my query returns me objects from the newest to the oldest.

I know I can add raw sql to the migrations, but it would be better if Django could figure it out for me.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: How about adding the ordering the `class Meta` like: `ordering = ['-date']`?

Comment: it doesn't produce any SQL on the migration. According to the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#ordering) it is useful for default ordering when retrieving objects. Actually, it says there is a performance cost on using it, which is the opposite of what I want.

Comment: There is a MongoDB engine that actually has that feature:
http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/model-options.html

Comment: Reading some docs out there: 
http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/order-by-asc-desc-nulls-last , http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createindex.html
 ... 
looks like adding DESC on a single field index does not affect the performance. Those two indexes I posted are equivalent. It would be nice to see if there is a solution for this, though.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I believe what you're after is now supported as of Django 1.11.

```
class Meta:
    indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['last_name', 'first_name',]),
        models.Index(fields=['-date_of_birth',]),
    ]
```

Official reference [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.indexes), [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/indexes/), and [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.11/#class-based-model-indexes).

Answer (score 4):

You would have to use your raw SQL to create the descending indexing as you want, but there are a few ways to achieve similar results without doing creating it.

You can accomplish your desired functionality by adding the `db_index=True` to the field and `ordering = ['-date']` [4] to the metadata of the model.

If you are only ordering by a single column then using Django's `ordering` with Postgres is not necessarily expensive. The Postgres planner/optimizer will decide [2, 3] whether to use indices or a full table scan and sort to form the relation.

To only perform ordering on a single QuerySet basis you can use the `order_by` [1] method. From the Django docs:

> ```
> Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2005).order_by('-pub_date', 'headline')
> ```
>
> The result above will be ordered by pub_date descending, then by
>   headline ascending. The negative sign in front of "-pub_date"
>   indicates descending order.

Another solution instead of using raw SQL would be to add the index field and then use the `reverse()` [0] method of the QuerySet with which you are trying to get the `date` field in descending order. This also requires the `db_index=True` and that a default `order_by` is defined for the field. This method is subject to the same caveats that setting `ordering` is, so steer clear of it if you are ordering based on multiple fields with differing scan directions.

Yet another solution is to override the default Django SQL template for index creation. The template is located at `django.db.backends.base.schema.sql_create_index` [5] but you might run in to unforeseen errors if you do this.

Citations since I can't post more than two links: https://bpaste.net/raw/6001004893c1

Comment: I am actually doing this in my query. I need to improve the speed by creating an index.

Comment: OK, I am updating my answer to reflect a change in the database rather than the query.

Comment: Wow, nice update. I'll test those options once I get in the office monday morning and let you know if any of them work. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't actually work for me, but I will select as the accepted answer because it answers my question (there is no way of doing exactly what I want, but there are a few other ways of achieving similar results)