# Disable default sorting of Django queries

Tags: sql, django, sqlite, sql-order-by

It seams that Django orders the result by default based on the primary key. In my application I need the reverse order, i.e. the most recent records always should be at first. I have viewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128610/can-i-remove-order-by-from-a-django-orm-query) with its answers which suggest using `order_by()` or `query.order_by()`. The problem that I have is that due to some reasons I should use [raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/) and they produce:

```
'RawQuery' object has no attribute 'order_by'
```

or:

```
'RawQuery' object has no attribute 'clear_ordering'
```

Based on the comments and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364597/django-models-add-index-on-date-desc-order) I created an index on the datetime field as follows:

```
class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['-created_at']),
        ]
```

But actually it does not help me.

Comment: If you use a *raw* query, you can not use any of these methods, since Django does not know how the query looks like, so no `.order_by(..)` or `.clear_ordering`, or anything of this.

Comment: But it is very rare that you need to work with raw queries...

Answer (score 0):

> The problem that I have is that due to some reasons I should use [raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/).

Once you use a raw query, then you can no longer use Django's ORM methods. A raw query means that you specify the query, so Django does not understand how the query works, so it can not change the ordering.

You thus should then do the ordering in the raw query itself. Something like:

```
MyModel.objects.raw(
    'SELECT app_name_table.id FROM app_name_table ORDER BY id DESC'
)
```

But it is very rare that the Django ORM can not help construct a query in an effective way. Therefore usually raw queries should be used as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks, I actually use this, but the problem is that ordering have its costs, that I am going to remove them. If it is actually raw why It returns results in reverse order if I do not use ORDER BY id DESC? because I insert records in desired order.

Comment: @keramat: if you would use `.order_by(...)` it will order at the database side for a "simple" queryset, so it does *not* order in Django/Python, but adds that to the database query. Usually ordering in the database is more efficient than doing this in Django/Python.

Comment: Can you answer me this question: why the raw query without ORDER BY id DESC returns results in ascending order (based on their id)? why it does not simply returns from the most recent records?

Comment: @keramat: without any `ORDER BY`, the database can return the records in any order. Depending on indexes, etc. that can be ordered by a certain field, but it can also be random, or some "ad-hoc ordering".

Comment: Thanks, I am using sqlite3 without indexing. I am getting results in ascending order every time. Is it related to sqlite3?

Comment: @keramat: then likely yes, but this is merely an "implementation detail" of the database.

Comment: So, what should I do? Should I define an index?

Comment: @keramat: you can add an index to boost ordering: but the ordering in the result without an ORDER BY can depend on all sorts of factors like filtering, ordering, subqueries, and change between release versions as well, etc. so there is no guarantee that this will change anything if you do not add an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @keramat: an index is not used to specify a "standard order": it is used to *boost* sorting and filtering, so make it faster. Defining an index does *not* mean that index will be used (per se). The database management system can decide to (not) use any of the indexes, so you *still* need an `ORDER BY ...` clause...